# JavaFX 2, Add items from ListView to TableView

Tags: listview, javafx-2, tableview

A TableView is filled by double left click on a ListView item(s).

This TableView has two rightmost columns rendered as ChoiceBox and CheckBox, and it all works fine.

My issues is as follow: add an item then set flag on the CheckBox and any number for the ChoiceBox colum

[image]

Now if I left click again on a ListView row to add another item to the Table, my previous check and number settings disappear

[image]

The whole project can be downloaded here

[ListViewAndTableView](http://www.filehostfree.com/?d=521614BD1)

Thanks

**Edit:** I forgot the following Properties methods

```
public SimpleBooleanProperty onProperty() {
          return on_col;
      }
      public SimpleStringProperty toolProperty(){
          return tool_col;
      }
      public SimpleStringProperty chartProperty(){
          return chart_col;
      }
      public SimpleStringProperty paneProperty(){
          return pane_col;
      }
```

With these methods added the CheckBoxes problems is now fixed, it only remains to fix the number selected on the ChoiceBox.

Answer (score 0):

When you call you `EventHanlder` for your `listviewIndicator` you do store your `Indicators` there with default values:

```
Indicators ind = new Indicators(indSelected, "", "", true);
```

If I understand your code correctly these values never change inside the list. So when you add another `Indicators` with another double click to your `ObservableList<Indicators> taToolsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` you still have two `Indicators` still with default values as mentioned above. As you in the following set the complete `taToolsList` to your `TableView` the before changed thingies are gone as the whole list is inserted.

```
tableviewIndicators.setItems(taToolsList);
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi nyyrikki, I have just updated my question with a partial solution found: will follow your suggestion to see if I can fix it all